# Is there a less-space taking way than using sprintf to format floats to strings?

Tags: c, printf, microcontroller

I am developing a C code for a microcontroller, this code takes input from sensors and outputs the data from the sensors along with other strings on an alphanumeric character LCD.
I generally use sprintf for this, but I came to notice that when using sprintf to format *floats* into strings, it takes up too much program memory space, which is quite low on a microcontroller.
(By too much I mean jumping straight from 34% of program memory to 99.2%)

So my question is, is there a less-space taking method to format floats into strings?
I only care about how simple the method is.

I use MPLABX IDE with XC8 compiler on a PIC16F877a 8-bit MCU.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The usual solution is to compromise range and the last few digit correctness and speed for a smaller code footprint.  Until you post how inaccurate the output is allowed and limited range of the FP, its all a guess. OTHO, the easy solution is to print FP like with `"%a"` (hexadecimal significand).  That takes little code.  Please provide detailed needs.

Comment: *"this code takes input from sensors"* And what is the format of that data? Are the sensors actually producing data in floating point format?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, 
I only need one digit after the decimal point.
The range of the number is -40 to +50.

I do not want it in hexadecimal format unfortunately, this is to be outputted to an LCD for a user to read.
I literally want to print this:
Temperature
23.4C

Comment: @user3386109, I have no problems in reading data from the analog sensors, I have no problems in the ADC result at all, I know the data is correct and is stored as floating numbers in the MCU, all I need is a less-space taking method than sprintf("%f").

You can assume *everything* before the sprintf is indeed correct.

Comment: On the contrary, converting the ADC result to a floating point number was indeed a major error.

Comment: @user3386109, I've worked before on PIC MCUs with larger memory, hence I have not met the problem before, I know how to deal with the sensors and internal peripherals.

Comment: @user3386109, what would you do if it represents a temperature from -40 to 50C?
Of course you have to map it.
This is what I did.

Comment: With only 1 digit after the decimal point, and a range of -40 to 50, there are only 900 possible values for the temperature. That's easily handled with fixed point math.

Comment: @user3386109, could you please guide me more?

Comment: What you've posted here is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to start a new question where you describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve. Specifically, what values are you getting from the ADC, and how do those correspond to temperatures.

Comment: Try `atof()` and disable floating point for `sprintf`.

Comment: @i486 fixed-point is a much better solution in this case. Store the value in 1/10℃, for example 234 for 23.4℃ and now just `printf("Temperature %d.%dC", temp/10, temp % 10)`

Comment: @phuclv Note: `printf("Temperature %d.%dC", temp/10, temp % 10)` better as `printf("Temperature %d.%dC", temp/10, abs(temp % 10))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a less-space taking way than using sprintf to format floats to strings?
> ... code takes input from sensors and outputs the data from the sensors along with other strings on an alphanumeric character

Do not use floating point at all.  [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67041493/is-there-a-less-space-taking-way-than-using-sprintf-to-format-floats-to-strings/67044308#comment118502091_67041493)

The reading from the sensor is certainly an integer.  Convert that reading to deci-degrees C using integer math and then print.

[TMP235](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmp235.pdf?ts=1618138932082&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsensors%252Ftemperature-sensors%252Fanalog%252Foverview.html) example

```
Temperature  Output
-40 C         100
  0 C         500
150 C        2000

#define SCALE_NUM ((int32_t)(150 - -40) * 10)
#define SCALE_DEN (2000 - 100)
#define OFFSET    (500)

int temperature_raw = temperature_sensor();
int temperature_decidegreesC = (temperature_raw - OFFSET)*SCALE_NUM/SCALE_DEN;
send_integer(temperature_decidegreesC/10);
send_char('.');
send_char(abs(temperature_decidegreesC/10) + '0');
```

Other improvements can be had, but avoiding FP variables and math and using integer math is the key.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of printf replacements available, but they are all not fully compliant to the standard, missing out certain functionality to get the code size down.

Some that I have used are [Mpaland printf](https://github.com/mpaland/printf) and [Menie printf](https://github.com/DerellLicht/snippets/blob/master/printf2.c)

There is also [Chan printf](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/printf.html) but it doesn't support float at all.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a less-space taking method to format floats into strings?

Just write the bytes and do the conversion on reader side. Knowing the endianess and format of the floating point number on microcontroller the reader needs to develop a *software* way reading of the floating point from bytes.

From [XC8](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/50002053g.pdf) documentation you know the format of floating-point number:

> Floating point is implemented using either a IEEE 754 32-bit format, or a truncated, 24-bit form of this.

You would do on microcontroller side just:

```
void send_byte(unsigned char b) {
    // send the bytes as is as binary - the simplest there is
    hardware_send(b);
    // or as hex readable number
    // depending on if you want it human readable or not.
    char buf[10];
    int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%#02x", b);
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
       hardware_send(buf[i]);
    }
}

void send_float(float data) {
    const unsigned char *b = (const unsigned char*)&data;
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < sizeof(data); ++i) {
        send_byte(b[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    float data = get_data();
    send_float(data);
}
```

this will cost, well, almost nothing to convert the data. Write your own byte->hex conversion and not use `sprintf` at all to save even more memory.

On the remote side, you would write software conversion to floating point number. Accumulate bytes into a buffer, fix endianess of input. Extract sign, mantissa and exponent using bitwise operations. In C you would then use [scalb](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/scalbn) to convert mantissa and exponent into a floating-point number and then just multiply by sign. But better choice is to use a more flexible programming language on PC side when possible - I would go with python.

But from the pragmatic side...

> on a PIC16F877a 8-bit MCU.

You would never ever use floating point numbers on a such small MCU. As you seem to want to transfer a temperature, an 32-bit `long` number expressed in milli-celsius will give you an endless range of temperature. But even a 16-bit `short` number expressed in centi-celsius will be more then enough. Do not use floating point numbers at all. Convert all your code to use integers only.

@subjective-side-note: My journey with XC8 has been more then unpleasant. The free version of XC8 generates very bad and unoptimized code and I enjoyed sdcc more. If this an amateur project I would suggest to move to STM32 (blue-pill for example) or Arduino (ex. ESP8266 even with wifi...), that are just cheaper, easier to work with, modern and gcc works on them.